# Dataflow zombie jobs - stuck in "Not Started" state

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

All of our Dataflow jobs have suddenly stopped working. They now just show "Not started".

When we kicked off one job it actually appears to have spawned numerous other jobs, which are all just hanging.

Is the service broken?

The list of job id's:

1. 2015-05-12_04_15_09-9449594780471772631
2. 2015-05-12_04_11_43-2832089474782567234
3. 2015-05-12_04_11_10-7703117482304158028
4. 2015-05-12_04_06_52-8133922783285731870
5. 2015-05-12_04_06_09-14187812688860505584
6. 2015-05-12_04_05_32-10296794562342944020
7. 2015-05-12_04_04_58-17815218306022481742
8. 2015-05-12_04_04_26-1948202417139012084
9. 2015-05-12_04_03_55-5718237782405777885
10. 2015-05-12_04_03_23-8040675812721773662

[image]

[image]

```
44227 [main] INFO  com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.PackageUtil  - Uploading PipelineOptions.filesToStage complete: 1 files newly uploaded, 77 files cached
Dataflow SDK version: 0.4.150414
446168 [main] WARN  com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.RetryHttpRequestInitializer  - Request failed with code 429, will NOT retry: https://dataflow.googleapis.com/v1b3/projects/gdfp-xxx/jobs
Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:54217', transport: 'socket'
446171 [main] ERROR com.tls.cdf.dfp.DFPDenormalizationCloudDataFlowJob  - Exception encountered while trying to execute "DFP Denormalization Job"
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to create a workflow job: (40153232ba863405): The workflow could not be created. Please try again in a few minutes. If you are still unable to create a job please contact customer support. Causes: (40153232ba8632a6): Your job could not be created. Please try again in a few minutes. If the service still isn't working please contact customer support. Causes: Internal Issue (7a518e51908b45c2): 64605561:22202 Causes: (33edae1682908f81): Too many running jobs. Project gdfp-xxxx is running 10 workflows and project limit for active workflows is 10. To fix this, cancel an existing workflow via the UI, wait for a workflow to finish or contact dataflow-feedback@google.com to request an increase in quota.
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.DataflowPipelineRunner.run(DataflowPipelineRunner.java:221)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.BlockingDataflowPipelineRunner.run(BlockingDataflowPipelineRunner.java:81)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.BlockingDataflowPipelineRunner.run(BlockingDataflowPipelineRunner.java:47)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.Pipeline.run(Pipeline.java:145)
    at com.tls.cdf.job.AbstractCloudDataFlowJob.execute(AbstractCloudDataFlowJob.java:100)
    at com.tls.cdf.CloudDataFlowJobExecutor.main(CloudDataFlowJobExecutor.java:44)
Caused by: com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 429 Too Many Requests
{
  "code" : 429,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "(40153232ba863405): The workflow could not be created. Please try again in a few minutes. If you are still unable to create a job please contact customer support. Causes: (40153232ba8632a6): Your job could not be created. Please try again in a few minutes. If the service still isn't working please contact customer support. Causes: Internal Issue (7a518e51908b45c2): 64605561:22202 Causes: (33edae1682908f81): Too many running jobs. Project gdfp-xxxx is running 10 workflows and project limit for active workflows is 10. To fix this, cancel an existing workflow via the UI, wait for a workflow to finish or contact dataflow-feedback@google.com to request an increase in quota.",
    "reason" : "rateLimitExceeded"
  } ],
  "message" : "(40153232ba863405): The workflow could not be created. Please try again in a few minutes. If you are still unable to create a job please contact customer support. Causes: (40153232ba8632a6): Your job could not be created. Please try again in a few minutes. If the service still isn't working please contact customer support. Causes: Internal Issue (7a518e51908b45c2): 64605561:22202 Causes: (33edae1682908f81): Too many running jobs. Project gdfp-xxxx is running 10 workflows and project limit for active workflows is 10. To fix this, cancel an existing workflow via the UI, wait for a workflow to finish or contact dataflow-feedback@google.com to request an increase in quota.",
  "status" : "RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED"
}
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException.from(GoogleJsonResponseException.java:145)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:113)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:40)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest$1.interceptResponse(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:321)
    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:1056)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:419)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:352)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:469)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.DataflowPipelineRunner.run(DataflowPipelineRunner.java:217)
    ... 5 more
```

Comment: We're investigating the issue.  Sorry for the trouble!

Comment: Any update @Sam McVeety?

Comment: The issue is now resolved. Your project should have quota again. Thank you for your patience!

Comment: Thanks Sam. What was the issue?

Comment: Basically, we hit a bug which resulted in your quota being reset.

Comment: What's the current quota for jobs/pipelines, and how do we get it increased?

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/faq#question-27

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's working once again. Seems to have been a problem with the Dataflow service itself.