# GCP Dataflow job sitting in "not started"

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow

I started 13 dataflow jobs ~ 43 minutes ago and they are all sitting in "not started". There are no logs in stacktracer or GCP logging. [Another answer on stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30189691/dataflow-zombie-jobs-stuck-in-not-started-state) had a googler fix the problem on their end.

I have tried all of the other answers I can find.

My dataflow api is enabled (I was running jobs with no issues 2 days ago, nothing has changed).
There are no logs to check, so dead end there. 
I have checked my quotas and none of them are throttling.

Any help from a googler or someone with other ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Where does the Dataflow job located? If us-central1, you might have been affected by the current internal issue. Mitigation work is continuing by our Engineering Team.

Comment: Workaround: Retry the job in a different region if possible. 
Note: The '--region' flag must be set explicitly if using the CLI or SDK. Ref: https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/concepts/regional-endpoints#using_regional_endpoints

Comment: @Ronnaver that is probably the issue. I will retry in another region. Side note. I checked the Google Cloud Platform status and "All services normal". But, when I just clicked through to the detailed portion then there was the note about dataflow having issues. Weird. Thank you for the very quick answer!

Answer (score 2):

Where does the Dataflow job located? If us-central1, you might have been affected by the current internal issue. Mitigation work is continuing by our Engineering Team.

Workaround: Retry the job in a different region if possible. Note: The '--region' flag must be set explicitly if using the CLI or SDK. Ref:  https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/concepts/regional-endpoints#using_regional_endpoints

It states now in the [Google Cloud Status Dashboard](https://status.cloud.google.com/), "Cloud Dataflow service is experiencing an issue with the creation of new Dataflow workflows in us-central1"